# iOS Core Data Associations

Tags: ios, core-data, associations

I've just started using CoreData in iOS and I'm confused by the associations on relationships. I am designing a database to model guitar chords, their notes and positions on the fretboard.

If I have a many to many relationship between chords and notes, since a note can belong to many chords while a chord can have many notes. If I select cascade as the delete rule, will this only delete the rows in the intermediate table (`chord_note` which I assume is automatically managed by CoreData) and not the notes for that chord?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

If you set the delete rule to be Cascade when you delete a Chord it will delete all related Notes.

In your case, you probably want Nullify as the rule. This will delete the Chord and remove the Chord from the Note's chord relationship (it will in fact delete the entry from the `chord_note` intermediate table you mention).